# Updating Fusion Table through Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables, google-oauth

so I've been trying to update a fusion table through the Google Fusion table API specified here:

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#updateRow

And I've run into a snag with authentication I believe. I've been trying to authenticate using OAuth 2.0.

So first the problem as it stands. This is how I'm generally building this thing. First I populate an array of items I want to update with the information FROM the fusion table:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT ROWID, ThreePartAddress, Latitude, Longitude FROM <table name> WHERE Latitude != '0' AND Longitude != '0' LIMIT 100&key=<key name>",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (m) { if (m != null) { meetings = m; } },
            error: function (e) { console.log(e.statusText); }
        });
    });
```

The meetings variable stores the intermediate table data I want to update with. Now I geocode the address pulled and then want to convert it and store the coordinates. I do that with the geocoding api (which only listens to the first 10 requests which is another issue I guess entirely).

```
function ProcessLatLng(geocoder, i, rows) {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': rows[i][1] },
            function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    // fire a query to update our lat lng
                    rows[i][2] = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    rows[i][3] = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                }
                else {
                    console.log('error geo: ' + status);
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

Now here's where I'm having problems. I go off and fetch a login token in OAuth. I pulled this from another question on StackOverflow. It seems to work but just once. I get my client id from the google :

```
var GOOGLE_AUTH_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";
     var GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = "blahblah.apps.googleusercontent.com";
     var PLUS_ME_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me";

     var button = document.createElement("button");
     button.innerText = "Authenticate with Google";
     button.onclick = function() {
       var req = {
         "authUrl" : GOOGLE_AUTH_URL,
         "clientId" : GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
         "scopes" : [ PLUS_ME_SCOPE ],
       };
       oauth2.login(req, function(token) {
            loginToken = token;
           }, function(error) {
             alert("Error:\n" + error);
           });
     };
     document.body.appendChild(button);
```

I look at the latitude and longitude in another function and update the meetings. Then I start looping over that array. I start building a query to update the table name then fire a POST request to get this thing going.

```
function uploadLatLngs() {
        for (row = 1; // first row (0) is column headers
                meetings.rows.length > row;
                row++) {

            var lat = meetings.rows[row][2];
            var lng = meetings.rows[row][3];
            if (lat != '' && lat != null && lng != '' && lng != null && !(lat == 0 && lng == 0)) {
                var data = "?sql=UPDATE <table name> SET Latitude = " + lat + ", Longitude = " + lng + " WHERE ROWID = '" + meetings.rows[row][0] + "'";

                var url = "https://www.google.com/fusiontables/v1/query/" + data;

                //"&access_token=" + loginToken;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    url: url,
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + loginToken);
                    },
                    success: function run(data) { console.log(data); }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

When I start firing these requests I get a CORS access error on every one.

```
OPTIONS https://www.google.com/fusiontables/v1/query/?sql=UPDATE%<Table name>,%20Longitude%20=%20-77.09161899999998%20WHERE%20ROWID%20=%20%2725%27 405 (Method Not Allowed) jquery-1.4.2.min.js:128
OPTIONS https://www.google.com/fusiontables/v1/query/?sql=UPDATE%20<table name>,%20Longitude%20=%20-77.09161899999998%20WHERE%20ROWID%20=%20%2725%27 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:53104' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I've only ever seen this work once and it only seems to happen if I use the: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ to generate an access token. I can't seem to get it working with my own client id.

What am I missing here? Here's a "sort of" view of my google dev console:

```
Client ID for web application
Client ID   XXXX
Email address   XXX
Client secret   XXXX
Redirect URIs   http://localhost:53104/GoogleMapsTest/Testing/oauthWindow.html
Javascript Origins  http://localhost:53104
```

oauthWindow is the window I'm authorizing from

Comment: you may want to add the google-fusion-tables to this question.

Comment: Why are you using the `plus.me` scope, when you actually want to update fusion tables (`fusiontables` scope)?

Comment: hmm I'm not sure! I pulled the authentication section from another example. What do you think I should do instead?